# Joining 2 tables where select highest value on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to Join 2 tables but only select values from table B where id is greatest and 2 columns match between table A & B.

I have tried this but it only selects 1 row due to the highest value of table 2 but I need the entire table A to be displayed.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT DocNum, Status 
    FROM TableB 
    WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM  TableB)
)
SELECT  TableA.DocNum, DocTitle, cte.Status
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN cte 
ON TableA.DocNum = cte.DocNum
```

example below:

```
Table A
    Id DocNum  DocTitle
    1  ST-0001 SomeTitle
    2  ST-0002 SomeTitle
    3  ST-0003 SomeTitle
    4  ST-0004 SomeTitle
    5  ST-0005 SomeTitle

Table B
    Id DocNum Status
    1  ST-0001 Incomplete
    2  ST-0001 Complete
    3  ST-0002 Complete
    4  ST-0003 Incomplete
    5  ST-0004 Incomplete
    6  ST-0004 Complete 
    7  ST-0005 Incomplete   

Result
    DocNum DocTitle Status
    ST-0001 SomeTitle Complete  
    ST-0002 SomeTitle Complete  
    ST-0003 SomeTitle Incomplete  
    ST-0004 SomeTitle Complete  
    ST-0005 SomeTitle Incomplete
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: `Join`,`Group by` are the solution

Comment: Have you tried with `Order By fieldname Desc` in `TableB` instead of `where` condition for `max id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE with Row_number to get only the rows with the max id per docNum from tableB, and then join to that cte.

First, Create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @A As Table
(
    Id int,
    DocNum char(7),
    DocTitle varchar(20)
);

DECLARE @B As Table
(
    Id int,
    DocNum char(7),
    [Status] varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO @A VALUES
(1, 'ST-0001', 'SomeTitle'),
(2, 'ST-0002', 'SomeTitle'),
(3, 'ST-0003', 'SomeTitle'),
(4, 'ST-0004', 'SomeTitle'),
(5, 'ST-0005', 'SomeTitle');

INSERT INTO @B VALUES
(1, 'ST-0001', 'Incomplete'),
(2, 'ST-0001', 'Complete'),
(3, 'ST-0002', 'Complete'),
(4, 'ST-0003', 'Incomplete'),
(5, 'ST-0004', 'Incomplete'),
(6, 'ST-0004', 'Complete'),
(7, 'ST-0005', 'Incomplete');
```

Then, create the cte with the row_number from tableB:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Id, 
            DocNum, 
            [Status],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocNum ORDER BY Id DESC) As Rn
    FROM @B
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT A.DocNum, A.DocTitle, CTE.[Status]
FROM @A A 
INNER JOIN CTE ON A.DocNum = CTE.DocNum
WHERE CTE.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
DocNum      DocTitle    Status
ST-0001     SomeTitle   Complete  
ST-0002     SomeTitle   Complete  
ST-0003     SomeTitle   Incomplete  
ST-0004     SomeTitle   Complete  
ST-0005     SomeTitle   Incomplete
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/RFVQ1983)

Comment: Thanks for that. If TableB doesn't contain the DocNum from TableA is it still possible to have the status appear in the resulting Table as Null or just empty? I need to keep all the DocNums from the original TableA in the Result along with Found Status alongside.

Comment: Yes, simply change the inner join to a left join.

Comment: I tried that but i haven't had any success. To run with your example i deleted id(7) from TableB and that resulting table didn't include id(5) from TableA when i would still like it to.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you should also move the condition on `CTE.rn = 1` to the `ON` clause if you are using a left join. [here is a rextester example](http://rextester.com/NRC69582)